# Identifying a Javascript object

Tags: javascript

I am having a problem identifying a javascript object

```
function A(x, y){

    this.boo = function(){
    }
}
var aa = new A("1", "2");
aa.boo();
```

In the code, is 'aa' a javascript object? Does it inherit properties from object.prototype too? If yes, how can I be sure (from a novice).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can be sure because **every** native object inherits from *Object.prototype* (except for the *Global* object, whose [[Prototpye]] is implementation dependant, but it is an instance of Object in most browsers).

#### Edit

Some clarifications.

**Native** objects are those constructed using ECMAScript, e.g.

```
function foo() {}
var obj = {};
var arr = [];
```

and so on. They all have *Object.prototype* on their [[Prototype]] chain, which makes them instances of Object (and whatever other constructor's prototype is on the chain). An ECMAScript object can inherit from more than one prototype and hence be an instance of more than one object:

```
function Foo(){}
Foo instanceof Function; // true
Foo instanceof Object;   // true

var foo = new Foo();
foo instanceof Foo;     //true
foo instanceof Object;  //true
```

**Built–in** objects are those supplied by ECMAScript, e.g.

```
Global   instanceof Object; // might be true
Array    instanceof Object; // true
Math     instanceof Object; // true
Object   instanceof Object; // true - Object is an Object :-)
Date     instanceof Object; // true
Function instanceof Object; // true
```

and so on. Most of the above are also instances of Function (including Function).

**Host** objects are those supplied by the host environment, such as everything in the DOM, e.g.

```
document
document.createElement
window
var element = document.createElement('img');
var nodeList = element.getElementsByTagName();
```

and so on. These object only have to follow the most basic rules of ECMAScript, they don't need to have any inheritance model and may even throw errors when simply tested with *instanceof* or *typeof* operators (which is a nasty behaviour but some versions of some browsers do - many IE host objects implemented as ActiveX controls do, hence their creation within try..catch blocks).

Read the section on "Native ECMAScript Objects" (ES 3) and "Standard Built-in ECMAScript Objects" (ES 5) objects in the specification (ECMA–262), it's all there.

Comment: Host objects aren't native objects and are outside the ECMAScript specification so they can do what they like. They need not implement any kind of inheritance at all.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "native object" in your post?

Comment: Why would this answer get a down-vote? @Jeremy: [Reference](http://es5.github.com/#x4.3.6) to "native object" in the spec. EDIT: [Here's a reference](http://es5.github.com/#x15.1) supporting the implementation dependence of the prototype of the global object.

Comment: *Built-in* objects are those defined in ECMA-262. Native objects are all the built-ins plus any constructed using ECMAScript (like those in the OP). Those supplied by the environment (e.g. the DOM in a browser) are host objects, you should not assume any kind of inheritance at all unless you are dealing with specific browsers that you know implement a certain kind of inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

> In the code, is 'aa' a javascript object?

Yes. Or more accurately, `aa` is a variable that *refers to* a JavaScript object.

> Does it inherit properties from object.prototype too?

From `Object.prototype`, yes. (Capitalization matters in JavaScript, because it's case-sensitive.)

> If yes, how can I be sure (from a novice).

I'm not quite certain what you mean here. In JavaScript environments, there are *host objects* (Section 4.3.8 of [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm)) and *native objects* (Section 4.3.6). Native objects all inherit from `Object.prototype`. Host objects may or may not.

There are lots of ways to query an object to find out what it "is". I outline several of them in [my blog post *"Say what?"*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/say-what.html), but to summarize:

- There's `typeof`, but regarding objects all it says is "object" (host or native), so that's not terribly useful if you want to know more about what kind of object it is.
- There's `instanceof`, which can be used to check if an object was created via a specific constructor function (e.g., `if (obj instanceof Date)`).
- There's a trick using `Object.prototype.toString`, which can sometimes give you more specific information about what kind of native object you're dealing with, if it's a *built-in object* (Section 4.3.7).
- Or you can stop worrying and learn to love the duck. E.g., don't worry about *what* the object is, just look to see if it looks like it has/does what you want ("duck typing").

Comment: +1 for "learn to love the duck" (not to imply the rest of your answer wasn't helpful).

Answer (score 0):

You can check its type:

```
if (typeof(aa) == "object") {
    alert("It's an object!");
}
```

which will cause an alert, meaning that it is an object, and also have any methods extended via object.prototype

Comment: @Jeremy Banks: absolutely correct, but I didn't think the detail was necessary since he was asking if the created object would inherit from object.prototype

Comment: @Jeremy - I think you have your terms wrong - ECMAScript defines built-in objects as native objects like Array, Math, Global and so on (ECMA-262 §4.2 para 4). Host objects **are not** builtin objects, they are host objects.

Answer (score 0):

Combining the previous two comments:

http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/x58w8/

```
function A(x, y){

    this.boo = function(){
    }
}
Object.prototype.foo = function() {};
var aa = new A("1", "2");
aa.boo();

alert(typeof aa);       // alerts object
alert(typeof aa.foo);   // alerts function
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use

```
if( Object.prototype.toString.call( aa ) === '[object Object]' )
{
    doSomething();
}
```